# Deploying repo to development

Tags: deployment, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Our current workflow setup is the following:
Dev server --> Repo/CI Server (In this case Gitlab/Gitlab-CI) --> Production Server

I want to deploy my current project to the production server. Right now I have a very simple ci file.

My problem is the following. Whenever the runner runs .my gitlab-ci.yml file I have problems regarding permissions (I suppose)

```
sudo: unable to resolve host vagrant
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
clonando
sudo: unable to resolve host vagrant

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

My .gitlab-ci.yml file is the following:

```
image: php56
before_script:
- bash server.sh 
job1:
    script:
        - php -v
```

This is my bash file:

```
echo -e "Logging to server \n"
sshpass -p Password ssh -T desarrollo@192.168.105.24
cd /var/www 
sudo git init
sudo git clone http://gitlab.panoramalife.com/cpadilla/PruebaDeploy.git
```

And it gives me this error.

How do I solve this?

Comment: you should give an explanation, not lots of code

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things which need to be fixed in order to get this running.

> sudo: unable to resolve host vagrant

This could mean that you changed the hostname of the machine but failed to edit the `/etc/hosts` and/or the `/etc/hostname`. Your new hostname needs to be in `/etc/hostname` and in `/etc/hosts` you need to have a line `127.0.0.1 <hostname>`. Now reboot the machine.

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

This happens because sudo prompts you for a password but can't because no terminal is present. You need to edit the sudoers file with `sudo visudo` and need to add the following line:

```
desarrollo ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/git
```

This tells sudo that this user doesn't need a password for using the git command.